# Why do FF and Safari position an object element different from other browsers when contained within a span and div?

Tags: css, css-position, html

I have the following test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .test {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span style="position:relative; left: 100px">
        <div>
            <object class="test" data="flash.swf">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
            </object>
            <div class="test" style="background-color: red; opacity: 0.5"></div>
        </div>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect that both the object and the div element whose class is "test" to be positioned the same. But it does not happen neither in FF nor in Safari. Why is that?
The div and span arrangement is a necessary condition for it to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. A span cannot contain a div.

Browsers are not always consistent in how they perform error recovery.

Write valid HTML and test it using [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 1):

`span` is an inline element it cannot contain other block elements. Add `display:block` to your `span` to make it block, then it will work.

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VegqQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

at first you need set for object `display: block` maybe this is the problem...

Comment: you need to add display: block also for span